# Using regular expression to find two series of digits separated by hyphen

Tags: regex

This is probably a very easy question for those who know regular expressions.

What is the regular expression to extract a substring that consists of 4 digits, then a hyphen, and then 5 more digits?

For example, in this string

```
I would like to extract 1234-66677 from this string
```

I want to get the "1234-66677" part.

It's always the same structure: 4 digits, hyphen, 5 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
/\b\d{4}-\d{5}\b/
```

`\b` are word boundaries, if you don't use them it will also match on longer digits like e.g. "123456-123456789"

See it [here online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v7a2)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that:

```
\d{4,4}-\d{5,5}
```

Comment: What's the difference between d{4} and d{4,4} ?

Comment: @ObiWanKenobi, none, except taking more space. :p

Answer (score 1):

That would be `/\d{4}-\d{5}/` - but the details depend on the language you are using.

Comment: [Word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) might be useful as well ... `\b\d{4}-\d{5}\b`